# Anylogic Problem with Pallete and Text Replaced with Random Characters

Tags: anylogic

I've been facing a weird problem in Anylogic. I've tried uninstalling and installing it again and trying this with different versions too. Yet nothing seems to solve it. When I start the program up, I'm greeted with a pallet and the main screen with the letters for the blocks replaced with random characters making it impossible to work with it. I haven't had any problems using the software on the same PC last year. Hope the community can help me solve it.

[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: Please provide more information, your Operating system, what version of AnyLogic you using etc. Have you escalated this to the AnyLogic support team?